# WSL 2 mac address filtering

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I've been asked to provide my MAC address presumably for an additional layer of filtering security.

Running `ipconfig /all` there is a ***Wireless LAN adapter WiFi*** physical address (windows) listed but also a ***Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL)*** (ubuntu) physical address.

Most of my 'work' will be done on ubuntu running on WSL2. I'm wondering which MAC address should I be providing - my initial assumption was I provide the Wireless LAN physical address but do I also need to provide the vEthernet (WSL) physical address?

TIA

Comment: Most likely the MAC address of your WiFi adapter itself, as unlike in the case of Ethernet, you can't really use multiple MAC addresses with one station. (AFAIK, Windows do it in a similar approach as `ipvlan` in Linux.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Short answer*:  Almost certainly the MAC of the wireless adapter.

*Explanation*:

WSL2 networking runs on a virtual network card (the "vEthernet" where the "v" is for "virtual") that is NAT'd (Network Address Translation) behind the Windows host's physical card.  This is similar to the way a router in your home will typically provide a single address (and MAC) for all of the computers and devices behind it.

The only MAC/address that the network you are connecting to will see is that of the host's Wireless adapter.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you.